# c++ partial method code reuse

Tags: c++, json, parsing, code-reuse

As part of a broader project, I've written a Json class in c++ that is able to parse and store in a tree hierarchy the json document structure.
The class uses a lexer to tokenize the json text source file and a simple set of parsing methods to build the json tree. The parsed json can then be browsed with classic tree traversal algorithms, modified if necessary, and finally rewritten back as a json text file.

I'm now looking for a way to reuse the parsing set of methods to perform different operations while scanning the input Json file.For example, instead of building the Json tree I would like to be able to create the Json pointers set within the same class.

Since it took me a while to debug the parsing algorithm, I was looking for a way to reuse the parsing methods while changing the actions to perform when a particular token is found.

As an example, when the parser reaches a token that identifies a scalar value (string, number, true, false, null) related to a key Json element, I would like to be able to create and attach a leaf tree node to the json tree, or compute the json pointer string that identifies that particular key in the Json document without duplicating the parse code or inserting a sequence of "if then else" or "switch" statements.

Here is the code of one of the parsing methods: parse_value()

```
template void JSONDoc::parse_value(void){

  string trimmedsymvalue;
  trimmedsymvalue=SYMVALUE;

  if(trimmedsymvalue.size() >= 2 && SYM != "NUMBER" && SYM != "NULL")
        trimmedsymvalue = trimmedsymvalue.substr(1, trimmedsymvalue.size() - 2);    

    if(SYM == "STRING"){
        CREATE_LEAF_NODE(JSONNode::NODE_STRING,trimmedsymvalue);
        return;
    }

// .....

    if(SYM == "LCBRKT"){
        parse_object();
        return;
    }

    if(SYM == "LSBRKT"){
        parse_array();
        return;
    }
}
```

In the above method, the call to CREATE_LEAF_NODE(JSONNode::NODE_STRING,trimmedsymvalue) creates a leaf node for the json tree. 
To be able to compute the Json pointer instead of attaching a leaf to the Json tree, at this point in the code I would have had to add an "if then else" or a "switch" statement.

In this particular case, the addition would not significantly affect code readabilty, but the actions needed to build the json tree during the parsing phase could be more complicated, and adding "if then else" or "switch" statements would result in a less maintainable code.

Is there a mean to achieve this without confusing or duplicating large portions of code?

f.

Comment: It sounds like you're essentially splitting it into a [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)-like layer (parse the document and emit callbacks) and a DOM-like layer on top (handle the callbacks and build the tree). These are XML terms, and there's a lot of complexity you won't need for json, but it's a reasonable place to start looking.

Comment: If that _is_ the case, your parser will be parameterized with an EventHandler object (using either runtime or compile-time polymorphism), and your existing DOM building code moves into an implementation of that EventHandler - as does the new code you want.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I was wondering if the c++ language features could help solve the problems. I thought about using lambda functions but  code readability would not improve very much

Comment: The language features that are likely to help are runtime or compile-time polymorphism. If you already know how to change the design, I'm not sure what the question is - are you asking how to code a callback handler?

Comment: I do not know how to change the design.How would you implement polymorphism in this case?

Comment: Do you know how to use polymorphism in the first place? I have literally no idea which part of this you're stuck on.

Comment: I know how to use it, but I think that in this case code readability would  not be preserved. How would you introduce poliymorphism in this scenario?